# How to get a lists of tasks that are unassigned, but completed by me?

Tags: asana, asana-api

I'm trying to fetch all the tasks that have been completed by me, irrespective of whether they have been assigned to me. Right now I'm pulling all the tasks that are assigned to me and completed by me using - 
'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/'tasks?assignee=me&workspace=' + workspaceId  +'&completed_since=' + date + '&opt_fields=completed,name,completed_at' ;

Then adding a filter to check if completed is true.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing a property along the lines of `completed_by` on a task object is in our list of potential additions to the API.

Given the current properties exposed in the API, there is a workaround, but it is not pretty.

A [Story](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/stories) will be generated on a task when it is completed.

Example task completion story:

```
{
  "id": 8675309,
  "created_at": "2013-01-11T00:28:25.630Z",
  "type": "system",
  "text": "completed this task",
  "created_by": {
    "id": 9531489,
    "name": "Andrew Noonan"
  }
}
```

In order to determine if you completed the task you will have to look for tasks with stories from the system with `text == "completed this task"` and `created_by.id == <YOUR_USER_ID>`.

Add `opt_fields=this.stories.(text|created_by)` to capture those fields when querying.